# How did I remove/change the color of the DateTimePicker from react-rainbow-components

Tags: reactjs, datetimepicker, react-rainbow-components

I am using React-Rainbow-Components to display a DateTimePicker:

```
import React from "react";
import { DateTimePicker } from "react-rainbow-components";
import { BsCalendarDate } from "react-icons/bs";

          <DateTimePicker
            id="datetimepicker-1"
            minDate={new Date()}
            formatStyle="large"
            className="border-none"
            icon={<BsCalendarDate color="#6B738D" />}
          />
```

But I want to remove the border, how can I do this?